Hearing back for job outcome
I have given interviews at two colleges in August but still not getting any email for decision? Not even rejection. At one place I inquired to a member of search committee and he said no official information is available but he said you lack experience of medicine teaching. But the head of search committee just replied to my inquiry that they have slowed down the process because of semester load so they will keep me updated. What should I assume?

All you can assume is what they have said explicitly. You haven't been rejected. Don't neglect to follow up on other opportunities.
The information from the committee head is probably a bit more important than from an arbitrary member, but only they know.

As I've mentioned in response to similar questions: we can't be certain, but if you haven't heard back from a recruitment committee after two or three months (since August), depending on the country, your chances are likely low. The common reasons for such delays are usually that the hiring committee ranked you lower and has already extended an offer to another candidate. While they wait for that candidate's acceptance, they haven't yet ruled out the lower-ranked applicants. In some institutions, even candidates who have been ruled out don't always receive a formal rejection notice due to various reasons, such as lack of organization or a cultural tendency toward non-transparency.
The information from the arbitrary faculty member is usually more reliable than that of the committee head: the latter is bound by regulations and other commitments of confidentiality, while the former isn't (or isn't aware of those) and is probably extending their honest opinion and internal knowledge.

But I am frustrated why can’t they just tell and send me rejection letter. I am waiting to hear back from two places.

Usually, they are lazy, or disorganized. I agree this shows some form of disrespect to those rejected, and is not okay.
